# Hide a certain category in layered navigation on search results

Tags: magento, navigation, hide, categories

I would like to hide just a single category from my layered navigation. I have the "Show in Navigation" set to no but it still shows up on search results page. Is there a way to hide this?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a single category from layered navigation please follow the below steps. Note you could do this for any type of category listing.

1. Open **/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEMENAME/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml**. If it does not exist, copy it from the base folder.
2. Find the code:

   ```
   <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
       <dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>
       <dd>
           <ol>
           <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>

               <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
               <li>
                   <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
               </li>
              <?php endif; ?> 

           <?php endforeach ?>
           </ol>
       </dd>
   </dl>
   ```
3. Add this if statement just inside the foreach loop (and dont forget to close it): 
   `<?php if ($_category->getId() != 22): ?>`
4. The new code will look like this:

   ```
   <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
       <dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>
       <dd>
           <ol>
           <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <?php if ($_category->getId() != 22): ?> <!-- If statement here, replace category ID -->
               <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
               <li>
                   <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
               </li>
              <?php endif; ?> 
             <?php endif; ?> <!-- End new If statement here -->
           <?php endforeach ?>
           </ol>
       </dd>
   </dl>
   ```
5. Replace the **category ID** with the ID of the category you wish to exclude.
6. To find out the ID of a category go to your Magento Admin panel and Categories, when you click to edit a category at the top left you will see it’s numerical ID.

Comment: template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml is not the layered navigation shown on SEARCH RESULTS page (it's just the catalog browsing nav), this is template/catalog/layer/view.phtml - however it appears to be an abstract listing nothing specific to categories.

Comment: OK you want template/catalog/layer/view.phtml

In this file you may find the following code:
     <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>

Youl need to filter out the filter name that we dont want.. <?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?>

Il check it for you when I get home!

Comment: maybe look at this http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/layered-navigation-but-not-quite/ . you may need to rewrite the way you list the layered options as outlined in this article. Then you can go ahead and filter the specific category using the method i mentioned above.

Comment: I do not mean to be difficult, but hard coding the check into a view file based on a text match is very bad practice. There is already a toggle in admin called "Show in Navigation" for each category - using this is a much more stable and future thinking solution.